# Using sed to search and replace in multiple files, with a start and end string

Tags: string, replace, sed, grep, find

We're trying to find or write a script using sed (or anything else really), that searches through every file in a directory (including subfolders), matching a start and end string, and then erasing the start, middle content and end string from the file.

Finding it tricky to find the exact command we need. Help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the grep man page?

Comment: grep finds text.  For modification of text you're going to want `sed`, or a language like awk or Perl.

Comment: Right, I guess we do. We'll do some googling now (we're not the best with linux). Do you have any sample commands?

Comment: I've amended the title to use "sed" instead of "grep", for better clarity.

Comment: I'd use `perl`, because this is exactly what a `range operator` is good for.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you can do with `perl` is exploit the [`range operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

As an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
     print unless m/START_TAG_HERE/ ... m/END_TAG_HERE/;
}

__DATA__
Some text 
more text
even more text
A line with START_TAG_HERE
some text to delete
don't want this
END_TAG_HERE
and this should print now.
```

You can make use of `File::Find` in order to recursively search a directory structure and do this. `perl` does also support in place editing (like `sed`)  but it's slightly complicated to combine with `File::Find`.

But you might find something like:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless m/START_TAG_HERE/ ... m/END_TAG_HERE/;' somefile
```

Will do the trick. Then you might be able to combine that with the `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps

Start Pattern='This'

End Pattern='testing'

Matching Start and End pattern

```
     grep -e '^This.*testing$' -R Foldername/
```

Remove  the start pattern

```
      grep -e '^This.*testing$' -R testing/  | sed 's/\('This'\)\(.*\)/\2/'
```

Remove the end pattern

```
      grep -e '^This.*testing$' -R testing/  | sed 's/\('.*'\)\('testing'\)/\1/'
```

Example :

Matching the start and end pattern :

```
  $  grep -e '^This.*testing$' -R testing/  
   testing/test/file3:This is for my best testing
   testing/test/file4:This is small testing
   testing/file2:This is for final testing
   testing/file1:This is for model testing
```

Removing the Start pattern

```
     $ grep -e '^This.*testing$' -R testing/  | sed 's/\('This'\)\(.*\)/\2/'
    testing/test/file3: is for my best testing
    testing/test/file4: is small testing
    testing/file2: is for final testing
    testing/file1: is for model testing
```

Remove the end patten

```
    grep -e '^This.*testing$' -R testing/  | sed 's/\('.*'\)\('testing'\)/\1/'
   testing/test/file3:This is for my best 
   testing/test/file4:This is small 
   testing/file2:This is for final 
   testing/file1:This is for model
```

Remove the start and end pattern

```
   grep -e '^This.*testing$' -R testing/  | sed 's/\('This'\)\('.*'\)\('testing'\)/\2/'
  testing/test/file3: is for my best 
  testing/test/file4: is small 
  testing/file2: is for final 
  testing/file1: is for model
```

Comment: What about removing start, end and everything in between? That's what I need.